# JSON_REMOVE nested item, MySQL

Tags: mysql, json, path, nested

pretty straightforward, i have the following JSON in MySQL:

```
{"car" : ["honda","ferrari"]}
```

i want to use JSON_REMOVE on "honda" alone, but i cannot find how to formulate the path. I thought it would go something like this, but it deletes all cars.

```
`update users set cars =
    JSON_REMOVE(cars, '$."car"', '$."honda"')
    where idUsers = 1;`
```

for some reason the MySQL docs do not cover this to my knowledge. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```sql
SELECT
  JSON_REMOVE(
    @`json`,
    JSON_UNQUOTE(
      JSON_SEARCH(@`json`, 'one', @`car_to_delete`, NULL, '$.car[*]')
    )
  );
```

See [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=9c51ccb70f29eea4b2a44540313c3d58).

Comment: thanks, that's what i was looking for. unfortunately i was messing around with JSON_SEARCH and now none of my functions work for inserting or updating data in the column. not sure what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

Please Try:-

```
JSON_REMOVE(value,'$.car.honda')
```